# Two rotated tables in one page

Tags: tables, rotating, ieeetran

I'm writing a paper using the `IEEEtran` style, which uses two column per page.

At some point, I had to make some two big tables, so I used `\sideways` to rotate them.

The pages' height fill all available space, but they are thin, and I could (and should) put two of them in the same page. I'm defining my tables like this:

```
\begin{table*}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Performance of Second Based Operators applied to the clown image.}
  \label{tab:sodclown}  
  \begin{sideways}
  \begin{tabular}{ ccc }
  ...
  \end{tabular}
  \end{sideways}
\end{table*}
```

How can I do so that they are in the same page if it is possible?

Comment: Do both tables have 3 `c` columns?

Comment: Yes. But each column has large contents.

Comment: Then you should be able to place them in a single `tabular` that you rotate with `\rotatebox{90}{\begin{tabular}{ccc}...\end{tabular}}`. All you have to do is put some empty line in the middle which would act as the separator between the two tables.

Comment: But I have to keep to different captions. This will not keep it, will it?

Comment: So you want horizontal captions with rotated `tabular`s?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fundamental thing to remember is that you can have multiple `\caption`s (and other constructs) within the same (single) float. So, the idea would be to place both `tabular`s in the same `table*`, each with their own caption. We can allocate 50% of the float width to each using a `minipage` of width `.5\textwidth`.

Here is way to achieve what you're after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[h]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{%
      \begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
      \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{Clown B.}\label{tab:clownB}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{%
      \begin{tabular}{ *{10}{c} }
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
        A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & J \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
      \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{Clown A.}\label{tab:clownA}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The above example sets each table in a `minipage`. Each `tabular` is rotated 90 degrees with a standalone `\caption`.